# Why is os.walk() not defining dirs or files?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, undefined, os.walk

I have this code in Python 2.7:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os
root=os.path.normpath('/home/andreas/Desktop/')

print root
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(root, topdown=True):
    break   
print(files)
```

Which works. It returns a list with the filenames in Desktop.
But when I change the path like:

```
 root=os.path.normpath('/home/andreas/Desktop/Some_Dir')
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'files' is not defined
```

This applies also for `dirs`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: cannot reproduce...

Comment: Just curious: why would one put break into the for cycle without any conditions?

Answer (score 2):

If `dirs` and `files` are not defined after your `for` loop terminates, that means `os.walk()` didn't yield any results – which means they never got assigned any value, and so remain undefined.

Here's a simple example of the same effect in action:

```
>>> for x in []:  # empty
...     pass
... 
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

```
>>> for x in [1, 2, 3]:
...     pass
... 
>>> x
3
```

The obvious explanation for `os.walk(some_path)` not yielding any results is that `some_path` doesn't exist or is inaccesible ... so presumably you don't have a `Some_Dir`, or you don't have permission from the OS to access it.

For example:

```
$ mkdir nope
$ chmod a-rwx nope
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 13 2017, 10:15:16) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk('nope'):
...     break
... 
>>> dirs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dirs' is not defined
>>> files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'files' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: cannot reproduce using `os.walk`, can you? (I'm using v3.4)

Comment: Ok, I understand, but how can i fix this problem? Because the folder is not empty

Comment: @adrian.andreas check for a spelling mistake or permissions problem.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus you're right, if directory doesn't exist, no exception and vars are not defined; weird!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, it's not the most intuitive behaviour.

Comment: `os.listdir` crashes for instance; I wonder how `os.scandir` (python 3.5) behaves.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Thank you, it was a problem with the permission

Comment: No problem :-) If an answer solves your problem, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it to let future readers know it's the correct solution.